# How to query an object from one model, starting from another model? Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make an association that is not working.
I have the following scope:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_04_05_125812) do

  create_table "accounts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "social_network"
    t.string "name_account"
    t.integer "person_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["person_id"], name: "index_accounts_on_person_id"
  end

  create_table "lists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "lists_people", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "list_id", null: false
    t.integer "person_id", null: false
  end

  create_table "people", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "post_text"
    t.date "date"
    t.string "link"
    t.integer "account_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["account_id"], name: "index_posts_on_account_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "accounts", "people"
  add_foreign_key "posts", "accounts"
end
```

I wish I could consult, for example:
I want to consult the person named "Test_name"

That person belongs to lists, which is a collection of people. In addition, that person has accounts and those accounts have Posts.

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :people  

end

class Person < ApplicationRecord
 has_and_belongs_to_many :lists
end

class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
  belongs_to :person

end


class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account 
end
```

How could I have a return like the one below:

```
List | Name      | social_network
1    | Test_name | facebook
2    | Test_name | twitter
```

All the queries I make, either return the wrong type, or return only the list.
Problems such as:

```
List | Name          | social_network
1    | Test_name     | facebook
2    | Test_name     | twitter
1    | Second_name   | twitter
```

And I don't want to see the data "second_name"

I try this:

```
@lists = List.from(
    Person.left_outer_joins(:list).where('people.name LIKE ?',  "Renata Rempel"),
    :list
  )
```

but, doesn't works =/

Comment: When you use `has_many` then the other side needs to have the `belongs_to` and the model with the `belongs_to` will hold the foreign key. When you want both sides to have many other things then you need to use `has_and_belongs_to_many` on both sides and you need an extra database table in between that stores the foreign keys – in your example, this seems to be the case for for `List` and `People`. The join table in the middle should be named `lists_people`. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-types-of-associations

Comment: right, but even making this change, I still can't see how to get a result the way I would like.  For example, I would like a List query, which given the person's name, would return me an @list that contains only the list with the searched name.  I thought something like List.joins (: people).where ('people.name LIKE?', ""% # {"Renata Rempel"}% "). But it didn't work = / I want a result like [list_id = 1, list.people.name = "Renata Rempel"], even though the list has other records, I wanted to show only that

Comment: I would expect this `List.joins(:people).where ('people.name LIKE ?', "%Renata Rempel% ")` to work. Can you please add some examples of how the data looks in your database to your question – for the `lists`, `people` and `lists_people` tables?

Comment: Your database schema doesn't match doesn't match the associations you defined. Your database says: `Person belongs_to :list` instead of `Person has_many :list`

Comment: Yeah, I create my schema again, but the problem Persist. My goal is that from the name of 1 person, I can return only the data related to that person's list, post, account.  It turns out that when I search the way I said up there, my return is lists that have that person, but also with information about another people that also belong on the list.  In SQL, this would work with right join, but it doesn't work here.

Comment: I updated with the changes and I try List.joins(:people).where ('people.name LIKE ?', "%Renata Rempel% ") and I don't have return with this query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start off with you want to setup a many to many association between Person and List. This can be done with `has_and_belongs_to_many` but there are [many reasons why `has_many through:` may be a better choice](https://cobwwweb.com/why-i-dont-use-has-and-belongs-to-many-in-rails). The primary one is that it will let you add features like keeping track of banned users or when a user joined a list.

```
# rails g model list_membership member:belongs_to user:belongs_to
class ListMembership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :member, class_name: 'Person'
  belongs_to :list
end
```

We then have to fix the foreign key in the association:

```
class CreateListMemberships < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :list_memberships do |t|
      t.belongs_to :list, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.belongs_to :member, null: false, foreign_key: { to_table: :people }
      t.timestamps
    end
    # can be a good idea to add a compound index
    # add_index [:list_id, :member_id], unique: true
  end
end

class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :list_memberships, foreign_key: :member_id
  has_many :lists, through: :list_memberships
  has_many :accounts
  has_many :posts, through: :accounts
end

class List
  has_many :list_memberships
  has_many :members, 
     through: :list_memberships
end
```

Your `from` query will not work as your actually selecting rows from `people` but you just alias the table `lists`. That won't magically select the right data! If you really wanted to use from you would do:

```
List.from(
  List.joins(:members).where("people.name LIKE ?", "Renata Rempel"),
  :lists
).eager_load(members: :posts)
```

If you want to create a bunch of lists with a random number of members in your seed file you can just do:

```
ids = 10.times.map do
  Person.create!(name: Faker::Name.name).id
end
lists = 10.times.do
  List.create!(member_ids: ids.sample(2))
end
```

Comment: With this representation, how would I have to create my objects?
I couldn't test it that way, I tried the following `lists = 5.times.map do 
  List.create!(name: "List #{Faker::Number.number(digits: 3)}")
end

10.times.map do |n|
    people = Person.create!(name: Faker::Name.name)
    people.list_memberships.create(
    list: lists[0] 
    )

    people.list_memberships.create(
        list: lists[rand(lists.size)]
    )
 
end
`
The error is: ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'person_id' for ListMembership.

Comment: Can associate them by doing `person.lists << list` or `list.members << person` or `list.member_ids = [1,2,3,4,5]`. There are many ways. You don't actually have to explicitly create the join row.

Comment: When I try this: `lists = 5.times.map do 
  List.create(name: "List #{Faker::Number.number(digits: 3)}")
end

people = 10.times.map do 
    Person.create(name: Faker::Name.name)
end

lists.each do |l|
    new_people_array = people.each_slice(2).to_a
    new_people_array.each do |p|
        l.members << p
    end`
don't work to, the error is SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.members. I trying on seeds.db

Comment: I tried this: `lists = 5.times.map do 
  List.create(name: "List #{Faker::Number.number(digits: 3)}")
end

people = 10.times.map do 
    Person.create(name: Faker::Name.name)
end

lists.each do |l|
    new_people_array = people.each_slice(2).to_a
    new_people_array.each do |p|
        l.person << p
    end
end`

Comment: With I change the models to
`class List < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :list_memberships
  has_many :person, 
     through: :list_memberships
end`

`class Person < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :list_memberships
    has_many :lists, through: :list_memberships
    has_many :accounts
    has_many :posts, through: :accounts
end` 
`class ListMembership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :person
end`

and I tried       @lists = List.from(
        List.joins(:person).where("person.name LIKE '%?%'", "#{query}"),
        :lists
).eager_load(person: :posts

Comment: Sorry I was a bit sloppy. I added the migration and it was missing `has_many :list_memberships, foreign_key: :member_id`. Also added an example of seed.